# Get a logical matrix which satisfies certain conditions based on row and column sub

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I have a matrix `A` of size say `5x7`.

If I want to get a logical matrix out of `A` based of the elements that satisfy certain conditions, I can do this:

```
A = [10    47    16    33    47    11    10
    19    39    26    19    44    16    12
    32    25    26    41    28    24     9
    40    22    41    27    32    12    12
     5    23    40    18    30    43    22]

>> A > 25 | A < 10

ans =

 0     1     0     1     1     0     0
 0     1     1     0     1     0     0
 1     0     1     1     1     0     1
 1     0     1     1     1     0     0
 1     0     1     0     1     1     0
```

---

**Problem:** If I want to specify conditions for the row and column indices, what is the best way to do it?

I have a condition like `i` (row sub) should be less than `j` (column sub).

I could do this using `triu` but is there any simple way using logical indexing?

**Expected output**

```
0    1    1    1    1    1    1
0    0    1    1    1    1    1
0    0    0    1    1    1    1
0    0    0    0    1    1    1
0    0    0    0    0    1    1
```

---

**Another example:**

**Size:** `5x3`

**Condition:** `(i > j+1) | i == 1 | i == 2`

**Expected Output:**

```
 1     1     1
 1     1     1
 1     0     0
 1     1     0
 1     1     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two types of conditions here, conditions on the location of elements, and conditions on the value of elements. What I'd do is create 2 matrices, one for the locations, and one for the values:

```
loc = triu(ones(size(A)),1)
val = A > 25 | A < 10
```

and then combine them using `or`:

```
or(loc,val) %// or loc|val
```

If you wanted to use logical indexing (i.e. not `triu`/`tril`/etc.), then I think you'd have to create matrices of indices and do logical indexing on them:

```
[I,J]=ndgrid(1:size(A,1),1:size(A,2))
loc=I>J+1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. `ndgrid` approach is good one. +1 for that :)

Comment: I would imagine directly constructing the matrix would be more efficient in general, but using logical indexing is easier. If this answer solved your problem, consider accepting it so that other people know it is resolved.

Comment: With `ndgrid` and logical indexing i could do like `loc = I > J+1 | I == 1 | I == 2` to get output directly. I can't do using `tril` in one step. I'll accept the answer within an hour if there is no better solution :)

Comment: Yeah those more complicated conditions will be much easier with logical indexing! Just making sure you weren't forgetting :P

Comment: After reading your answer, i got an idea to solve this using `bsxfun`. :)

Answer (score 3):

I figured an approach using [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)

```
[rows, cols] = size(A);

out = bsxfun(@(A,B) A > B+1 | A == 2 | A == 1 ,(1:rows).',1:cols);
```

Results:

```
>> out

out =

 1     1     1     1     1     1     1
 1     1     1     1     1     1     1
 1     0     0     0     0     0     0
 1     1     0     0     0     0     0
 1     1     1     0     0     0     0
```